# Linux command to convert powerpoint (pptx) to pdf

Tags: linux, command-line, pdf

I have a pptx file that I would like to convert to pdf. Is there a way to do it from the command line using linux?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have `LibreOffice`, you can use this command:

`soffice --headless --convert-to pdf inputfile.pptx`

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do it without having to install libre office?

Comment: You might use `unoconv` https://linux.die.net/man/1/unoconv

Comment: unoconv needs libreoffice.